# Objects are not valid as a React Child (found: object with keys{}), but the child is an array

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am trying to generate a React Native Flatlist from an array of objects.  I thought it was working before (I took a break from this project and am just coming back to it after a month or so), but now I'm getting the error 'Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).  If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

The variable 'tools' is an array, and when I replace it with an empty array everything works fine, so I know the issues is with the tools variable.

This is the screen that I'm trying to render:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Pressable, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { defaultStyles } from '../theming/styles';
import { COLORS } from '../theming/colors';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { HomeStackParamList } from '../navigation/HomeStack';
import useFetchTools from '../hooks/useFetchTools';
import { Tool } from '../models/Tool';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setToolId } from '../redux/toolIdSlice';

type NavProps = NativeStackScreenProps<HomeStackParamList, 'Catalog'>;

export const CatalogScreen = ({ navigation }: NavProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { tools, refetchTools } = useFetchTools();

  const handleBackPress = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  const handleItemPress = (item: Tool) => {
    dispatch(setToolId(item.tid));
    navigation.navigate('ToolDetails');
  };
  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Tool }) => {
    return (
      <Pressable
        style={styles.renderItemView}
        onPress={() => handleItemPress(item)}>
        <Text style={styles.toolNameText}>{item.name}</Text>
      </Pressable>
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('TOOLS: ', tools);
  }, [tools]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.safeAreaView}>
      <SafeAreaView />
      <View style={styles.pageHeaderRow}>
        <Pressable onPress={handleBackPress}>
          <Icon source="chevron-left" color={COLORS.defaultGrey} size={30} />
        </Pressable>
        <Text style={styles.pageHeaderText}>My Tools</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        {/* TODO: Add 'sort by' option - brand, category, date added etc */}
        <View>
          <FlatList
            data={tools}
            keyExtractor={item => item.tid!}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            numColumns={1}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pageHeaderRow: {
    ...defaultStyles.row,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  pageHeaderText: {
    ...defaultStyles.pageHeaderText,
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  renderItemView: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginVertical: 5,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.defaultLightGrey,
  },
  safeAreaView: {
    ...defaultStyles.safeArea,
  },
  toolNameText: {
    ...defaultStyles.textTitle,
  },
});
```

and this is the useFetchTools() hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import { Tool } from '../models/Tool';
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const useFetchTools = () => {
  const [tools, setTools] = useState<Tool[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const fetchTools = async () => {
    console.log('Attempting to fetch tools');
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection('tools')
        .where('owner', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .get();
      const toolData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return doc.data() as Tool;
      });
      setTools(toolData);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error fetching tools: ', err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTools();
  }, []);

  return { tools, loading, refetchTools: fetchTools };
};

export default useFetchTools;
```

I can't figure out what's going on, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - even though my data was an array, in some of the objects the name field was incorrectly stored as an empty object.  I found this by changing the  component to TEST ITEM and then putting a console.log statement immediately before the return of my render item function, and printed item.name for each iteration.